# OS X Sending syslog to a remote box

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, syslogd

For some reason I have a hard time wrapping my head around how OS X handles things like init, cron, and "normal" daemon maint.  Too many years spent doing *nix work.

How do I configure syslogd on a 10.6 OS X box to send logs to a syslog server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

was a simple matter of adding:

```
*.*       @remote_ip
```

to /etc/syslog.conf

Then issuing

```
launchctl stop com.apple.syslogd
launchctl start com.apple.syslogd
```

*sigh* whatever happened to /etc/rc.d/init.d/syslogd restart. . .

Comment: @skarface: Apple replaced cron and init with `launchd` in Mac OS X 10.4 (http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html). It's really not that bad at all once you get to know it.